# Can NDepend detect where string interpolation is used in C#?

Tags: logging, static-analysis, serilog, ndepend

I'd like to enforce a rule that log statements do not use string interpolation:

Example
`Log($"Added {count} messages.");`

Instead I want to encourage/force developers to use structured logging, which means passing values in as separate arguments to a Log method that supports this concept.

How would one use NDepend to do this, assuming it's possible? If not NDepend, can it be done with a Roslyn analyzer?

Answer (score 1):

[SerilogAnalyzer](https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer) is a Roslyn-based analyzer that will do that for you.

[image: SerilogAnalyzer Example]

Answer (score 0):

Since string interpolation results in a call to `System.String.Format(String,Object)` you can write such a rule with [NDepend CQLinq](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-syntax):

```
//<Name>Don't use string interpolation from Log method</Name>
warnif count > 0 
from m in Application.Methods where m.IsUsing ("System.String.Format(String,Object)")
where m.ParentNamespace.Name.Contains(".Log")
select m
```

[image: String interpolation calls string format]